# I'm having problem with my sample project

Tags: php, pdo

edited...

hi guys can anyone help me with my website

I just want to get a specific comment in the comment area just like in facebook

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postID = postID';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$comment = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

what I mean is that if I comment in the first post it will just fetch the current comment and it will not display on the other post.

Comment: Your SQL condition `postID = postID` literally says `any comment`. You need to pass actual post ID there.

Comment: @alx how can I do it ?

Comment: @David i dont receive any error

Comment: @RolandoAbu: I wouldn't expect you to receive an error.  Think about this logically... You want to get comments for a specific post, right?  How are you telling the code *which* post?

Answer (score 2):

I believe answer would look like this:

```php
<?php 
require 'db.php';
$postId = 1; // get it somewhere, probably from $_GET
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postID = ?';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute( [$postId]);
$comment = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

Explanations, copied from comment to original question:

> Your SQL condition postID = postID literally says any comment. You need to pass actual post ID there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your query is currently doing:

> get records from the table comment where the field postID = postId

Which of course, won't work, you're using a string (without quotes) as your value. You need to bind the parameter and pass the value in, e.g.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `some_field` = :myVal;';
$res = $conn->prepare($sql);
$res->execute([':myVal' => $_GET['id']]);

$data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here, I pass the bind a param (`:myVal`) and then prepare that statement. You then pass in the value for `:myVal` (in this case, a `$_GET` of the query param `id`).

Then fetch, `var_dump`/`print_r` that, and you should see table data in your script.

Comment: there's nothing to $_GET['id'] cause the link doesn't have any id, what's in the index.php is all the post and I just want to get the comment for the spicific post

Comment: What? My code is an example (as mentioned) - did you try changing it to suit you?

Comment: there is two posts in my index.php the first is "Hello I'm" and the second post is "Hello my name is" now I want to get the comment with their specific ID's the first post has the id of 10 and the second post has the id of 9 now both post is displaying the same comment ID

Comment: Then get the id and pass it into the `execute()`? What are you getting tripped up with?

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `postID` = :myVal;';
$res = $connection->prepare($sql);
$res->execute([':myVal' => $_GET['postID']]);
$data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

that is why I did and i'm getting error  Undefined index: postID